# Javascript: export table as excel with certain row height

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel

I'm using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/755203/Export-HTML-table-to-Excel-With-CSS) function to save a table as an excel file. I've tried adding inline CSS `height:0` into a `tr` and `td`, but it doesn't give any effect. Is there any other way to export with correct row height?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan='2'>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height: 0'> <!-- no effect -->
    <td colspan='2' style='height: 0'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Despite this is out of the topic, I would personally highly recommend you to use a server-side library, such as PHPExcel, that does any kind of job very beautifully. I've tried many and many times using javascript for such a task but it always came out in different ways according to several parameters, such as browser type, version and so on.

Comment: The HTML `<tr style="display:none">` leads to a hidden row in Excel. But I'm not sure with your HTML as it is not really senseful HTML table construction.

Comment: I need that `td` to contain another `table` (nested table)

Comment: Yes, but your "rospan" is nevertheless not senseful. Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/94tLhmem/2/ The export to excel leads to hidden rows 2 and 3. With `<tr style='display:none'>` then the rows are hidden in HTML also.

Comment: yes, it's hidden in the html, but not in the excel, or maybe because I'm using LibreOffice Calc?